# Intalling ejabberd on AWS ec2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, xmpp, ejabberd

Trying to install ejabberd on ec2, tried many things but nothing seems to be working.

results of some commands

**cat /etc/os-release:**

```
VERSION="2015.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2015.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2015.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2015.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
```

**sudo yum install ejabberd:**

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
984 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No package ejabberd available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Is it possible to remove priority protections and whether it is a good idea or not?

Then how can I possibly install ejabberd using "yum install ejabberd" ?

I am new to linux 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Download binary from: https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/

Install binary file using:

```
chmod +x ejabberd-15.04-linux-x86_64-installer.run
sudo ejabberd-15.04-linux-x86_64-installer.run
```

Fill in the details and u will be done with the installation.

Go to installation directory

```
start the ejabberd service: bin/ejabberdctl start
status of ejabberd service: bin/ejabberdctl status
stop the ejabberd service : bin/ejabberdctl stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use binary installer from ProcessOne or RPM package ?
It is available on official download page: https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/